# Store a reference to the user that makes a modification of data through Django-admin

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-admin

I want to store a reference to the user that makes a modification of the information through Django Admin. Basically, i want to know who did a change:

For example:

```
class Calibrations(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    #Some reference to the user that made the change has to be stored
    responsable_user = models.PositiveIntegerField() #An id?

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.responsable_user = get_current_loggedin_user().id
        super().save()
```

### Is there a way to store this user reference on a model? Or maybe i better way of solving this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you can do it like this. First create FK to User Model

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model


class Calibrations(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    responsable_user = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(), on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, null=True, default=None)
```

Then override the [**`save_model()`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.save_model) method of admin class for `Calibrations` model:

```
class CalibrationsAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        obj.responsable_user = request.user
        super().save_model(request, obj, form, change)
```

Answer (score 1):

General approach is to use django's built-in User model as a ForeignKey in your model such as:

```py
# models.py
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Calibrations(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    responsible_user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Then you can create and then filter `Calibrations` object by:

```py
# views.py

def create_view(request):
    calibrations = models.Calibrations()
    calibrations.responsible_user = request.user

def filter_view(request):
    calibrations = models.Calibrations.objects.filter(responsible_user=request.user)
```